# Java code race condition multi-threaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have some code, and I want to know whether in a multi-threaded environment I could lose data...

Here's the example code:

```
public class TestingJavaThreading {
    private final Map<String, Set<String>> data = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
    private final HttpClient client;
    private final AsyncDataProvider provider;
    private final String baseUrl;

    // This method is called first...
    public void init(String code) {
        // We initialise the set to ensure it doesn't throw a null pointer exception or something weird...
        data.put(code, Sets.newConcurrentHashSet());

        // We tell the provider we're interested in data...
        provider.subscribeToDataFrom(code);

        // This HTTP call may take long time, and we can't afford losing data, that's why we subscribed beforehand in the previous line...
        List<String> elements = client.request(baseUrl + code);

        // We add all of the new elements, meanwhile some elements may have been added by "onMessageFromProvider"
        data.get(code).addAll(elements);

        data.get(code)
            .stream()
            .map( /* some transformations here, whatever... */)
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));

        // Now we've printed the merged data from "onMessageFromProvider" + the HTTP call
        // We remove the element from the map, so now we only receive data from "onMessageFromProvider"
        data.remove(code); 
    }

    public void onMessageFromProvider(String code, String element) {
        final Set<String> newSet = data.computeIfPresent(code, (k, v) -> {
          v.add(element);
          return v;
        });

        if (newSet == null) {
            // Do something else...
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, the initial method being called is `init`. The steps are like this:

1. Initialise the CHM to guarantee it contains data
2. We have a provider that gives us information in real-time about that element, but it doesn't provide the past data for it. When data comes from the provider, it calls the method "onMessageFromProvider"
3. In order to get the previous data for the item, we need to do a separate HTTP call, and then merge the data that came to "onMessageFromProvider" with the results from the HTTP call. After that's done, we can rely entirely on whatever "onMessageFromProvider" is doing
4. Once we have the result from the HTTP call, we merge it with the data that came from "onMessageFromProvider" meanwhile, we apply transformations, and we print the resultant merged set
5. Now we remove the map key, so we can entirely rely on whatever "onMessageFromProvider" is doing

Could this lead to potentially losing data while the step (3) is running? How can I solve it? Where should I put more code in order to rely as little as possible on `synchronished`?

So resuming, my aim is to never lose data, and I want to make sure that's 100% guaranteed with my algorithm.

Sorry for the loooong post, hope it makes sense.

**UPDATE**

Based on input, I'm updating the code with a real sample, currently looks like this:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Main().init("X");
  }

  public void init(String code) throws InterruptedException {
    subscribeToDataFrom(code);

    CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(getDataFromHttpRequest());
  }

  private Supplier<Set<String>> getDataFromHttpRequest() {
    return () -> {
      Set<String> resultsToReturn = Sets.newHashSet();
      try {
        resultsToReturn.add("B");
        resultsToReturn.add("C");
        resultsToReturn.add("D");
        resultsToReturn.add("E");
        resultsToReturn.add("F");
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulate it is a slow request...
      } catch (Exception ex) {}

      return resultsToReturn;
    };
  }

  private void subscribeToDataFrom(String code) {
    Runnable r = () -> {
      while (true) {
        onMessageFromProvider(code, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      }
    };

    new Thread(r).start();
    new Thread(r).start();
    new Thread(r).start();
    new Thread(r).start();
    new Thread(r).start();
  }

  public void onMessageFromProvider(String code, String element) {
    // Here how do I create the completable future for usage in the previous CompletableFuture????

    final Set<String> newSet = data.computeIfPresent(code, (k, v) -> {
      v.add(element);
      return v;
    });

    if (newSet == null) {
      System.out.println("Ok, now I can do something different with: " + element);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CompletableFuture class, have methods to combine and execute differents tasks

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html :

- Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture, or by any other caller of a completion method.
- All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task). To simplify monitoring, debugging, and tracking, all generated asynchronous tasks are instances of the marker interface CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask.
- All CompletionStage methods are implemented independently of other public methods, so the behavior of one method is not impacted by overrides of others in subclasses.

For example :

```
  CompletableFuture<String> httpTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                                 () -> new HttpTask(httpClient));

  Set<String> result = httpTask.thenApply(elements -> //onMessageProvider method       
                   // maybe you can create a Callable class with the logic)

          .thenApply(mergedElements -> //remove code).get();
          //or try another method


  class HttpTask extends Callable<List<String>>{

    private HttpClient client;

    public HttpTask(HttpClient client){
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> call() throws Exception {
      return client.httpCall(...);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Hey! that looks and sounds great, but unsure how can I use it in my code, and how it would help? Are you saying that I should create a `private final CompletableFuture` and supply stuff to it? But then I'd still need to have the `data`, and would need to synchronise on it?

Comment: Would you mind adding an example that is more related to mine, so I can make sense of it? BTW, reading more now about `CompletableFuture`

Comment: thanks for the edit, but I still don't see how this would avoid or help with my race condition, if any?

Comment: with completableFuture, the forkjoin  is responsible for manage the tasks, so you wouldn't have race conditions

Comment: ok, I'll rewrite my example and show you. If you tell me it works, then I'll stick with that :P

Comment: I'm sorry I'm half way through but I think you missed something: I don't explicitly call `onMessageFromProvider`, It's just a method that gets called from some outside threads. So I can't "request" it manually. That external code just gives me `String` instances that I add to my set, until I received the response from the HTTP call... Am I making sense? I'll provide the current code as I have it

Comment: I've added my code, that I'm trying to change. Can you point me out how to continue please?